# always getting null value while reading a txt file

Tags: android

I am using the below code to read the value from a text file. But, always null value is read (**versionfile** is null always) . Am i missing something in the code? *(Note: the file is existing and values are there in it)*

```
String fileversion = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "chk.txt", versionfile = "0";
File chkfile = new File(fileversion);

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(chkfile));
    while ((versionfile = br.readLine()) != null) {

    }
    br.close();
} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

Comment: Have you given permission ?

Comment: yes, both write and read

Comment: have you chkfile.isExist() file? For identify file is exist or not

Comment: file exists and it is completing the while loop without any exception or error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

`while` loop was executing 2 times and my file had only 1 line, So the value was replaced by null on 2nd time. As per the requirement the file will always have single line content. So ,i removed the `while` loop and it is working fine.

```
String fileversion = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "chk.txt", versionfile = "0";
File chkfile = new File(fileversion);

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(chkfile));
    versionfile = br.readLine();

    }
    br.close();
} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the file you mentioned doesnt exist because when I executed this code in my device it worked perfectly and displayed the output in log

```
String fileversion = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Links.txt", versionfile = "0";

File chkfile = new File(fileversion);

Log.e("///////////////", "versionfile :: " + versionfile + " : fileversion :: " + fileversion);
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(chkfile));

    while ((versionfile = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.e("///////////////", "versionfile ::" + versionfile + ": fileversion :: " + fileversion);
    }
    br.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

This is what I have done exactly the same you did

Your code is perfect you just need to store the version string in another sting like

```
newString += versionfile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
String fileversion=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "chk.txt", versionfile="0";
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileversion);
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    while ((versionfile = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("versionfile");
    }
    br.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Instead of System.out.println, you can use LOG.E

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to read .txt file:

```
// Read text from file
public void ReadBtn() {
    //reading text from file
    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn = openFileInput("mytextfile.txt"); // define your path.
        InputStreamReader InputRead = new InputStreamReader(fileIn);

        char[] inputBuffer = new char[50];
        String s = "";
        int charRead;

        while ((charRead = InputRead.read(inputBuffer)) > 0) {
            // char to string conversion
            String readstring = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead);
            s += readstring;
        }
        InputRead.close();
        Log.d("File Data", s);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I hope you added below permission into manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```